# Is there an easy way to let visitors change the font size of the webpage in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, font-face

The Problem is the following: I want my wordpress website to be as inclusive as it can be and would like the  option of having it displayed in a dyslexic friendly font. These fonts usually do not look very nice to people that do not struggle with reading since they aure usually expecting the basic fonts like Arial etc.

Is there a way (Button or Menu) for the visitor to change the site-wide default font for their session?

I have not tried coding anything, looked at a lot of plugins but I did not find one that did what I want. Happy to either receive suggestions as to best code that as a custon HTML or points to some widget that already exists (preferred)